# How can I make Finder start not in "All my files"

Tags: finder

I don't like that Finder shows me "All My Files":

[image: Finder sows some useless stuff]

It also delays Finder start a little.

How can I make Finder start in some different place (not in "All My Flies")?
Can finder start in my home directory `~` or anywhere here:

[image: places]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can change this in `Finder > Preferences > General > New Finder windows show`. I've set mine to my home directory, but you can also choose `Other...` and set a different directory

[image]

Comment: thank you for this tip, it's been driving me nuts for a while, haha! Much appreciated!